# Highcharts responsive legends relative to the chart area

Tags: highcharts

I would like to hide the legend if it takes too much vertical space relative to the total height of the chart. Highcharts offers a callback to specify the condition if a responsivity rule should be applied, but the best I can do is to estimate the height of the legend, which is not optimal:

```
// Hide legend if it's height takes more than 40% of the total height
const verticalThreshold = 0.4
// This is an empirical constant which tries to estimate the average width (in px) of one legend item
const estimatedItemWidth = 260

const shouldHideLegend = (chart) => {
    const availableWidth = chart.renderTo.clientWidth - chart.legend.padding * 2
    const availableHeight = chart.renderTo.clientHeight
    const legendItemCount = chart.legend.allItems.length
    const estimatedColumnCount = Math.max(1, Math.floor(availableWidth / estimatedItemWidth))
    const estimatedRowCount = Math.ceil(legendItemCount / estimatedColumnCount)
    const estimatedHeight = estimatedRowCount * (chart.legend.itemHeight + chart.legend.itemMarginTop + chart.legend.itemMarginBottom)
    return estimatedHeight / availableHeight > verticalThreshold
}

const config = {
    // ...
    responsive: {
        rules: [
            {
                condition: {
                    callback: function() { shouldHideLegend(this) }
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Simply using condition.maxHeight is not enough for your case? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.condition.maxHeight If your case is more complicated could you reproduce it with sample data on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: No, `condition.maxHeight` is absolute, which is insufficient for me. For instance, if there are only a few legend items, then it could be easily displayed on a small chart, so why not show it.

Comment: So maybe use the `chart.events.render` to check how many legend items applied after each redraw and after some condition use `chart.update to` add this `condition.maxHeight`? https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update